# Noun or adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

My dad is (a) racist.

In this sentence, is 'racist' used as a noun or an adjective? If it is used as an adjective, then is this sentence correct without the article?

Comment: *Racist* is a description, so it's an adjective; *a racist* is somebody who fits the description, so it's a noun. They're both correct and mean almost the same thing.

Comment: "My dad is a racist" = noun

Comment: "My dad is racist." = adjective

Comment: Related: [Adjectival Usage of Racist](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337849)

Answer (score 1):

Using a definite ("my dad is the family racist") or indefinite ("my dad is a racist") article makes "racist" a noun.  Otherwise the syntax makes it an adjective.

Not many words are that mutable.